# Pull infomation using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Does anyone know how to get the date from this using scrapy?

```
'<a href="/realDonaldTrump/status/988856839893897222" class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" title="12:06 PM - 24 Apr 2018" data-conversation-id="988856839893897222"><span class="_timestamp js-short-timestamp " data-aria-label-part="last" data-time="1524596817" data-time-ms="1524596817000" data-long-form="true">Apr 24</span></a>']'
```

I obtained this text using

```
 response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip")]').extract()
```

I'm after the information after the "title="
I'm kinda new so if you could explain why it works even better, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below xpath to get the date you wish to parse. The date is within `title` attribute. When you wanna get the value stored within any attribute, you need to call it using it's key like dictionary. Having said that the `key` here is `title` and the `value` is `12:06 PM - 24 Apr 2018`.

```
xpath("//a[contains(@class,'tweet-timestamp')]/@title").extract_first()
```

Output:

```
12:06 PM - 24 Apr 2018
```

Comment: you're a superstar thank you so much! Id give you rep but like i said i'm new.

Comment: You are welcome. If it serves the purpose, don't forget to tick the grayed out checkmark between the up/down buttons next to my answer to select it as the accepted solution.

Comment: Yeah i cant because i dont have enough rep it's not because i didnt know how thanks tho.

Answer (score 1):

Get the date in milliseconds contained in @data-time attribute and parse it.

```
d=float(xpath("string(//a[contains(@class,'tweet-timestamp')]/span/@data-time)"))
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Output

```
'2018-04-24 16:06:57'
```